# How to show changes in GridView in Android step by step like animation?

Tags: android, gridview

I use GridView in my Android app.
When I touch some cell I want to show user an animation, for example movement cell content from one cell to another.
For that I set different ImageAdapter to GridView, but it is shown only last view.
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

you shoud try the sample api-demo from android sample directory is contain animation that you want in your application